# Integration of a complex valued function in $[a,b]$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, holomorphic-functions

Let $f:X→\mathbb{C}$ be a complex function which is holomorphic, where $X$ is a domain of $\mathbb{C}$. It is given that $f(z)=z^2g(z)$ for some holomorphic function $g:X→\mathbb{C}$ and $\int_{X} f(z) \mathrm{d}x=0$.

Then a question come in my mind that is $\int_{X} g(z) \mathrm{d}x=0$ also?
If this integral in not zero for some $g$, then please help me to show it by some counterexample.

Comment: What does "holomorphic" mean if the domain is an interval in the real numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I have done a mistake. That will be a path $X$ from $a$ to $b$. Then I have to define the functions. Now i have edited it. @Arthur

Comment: If $X$ is a path, then what is the name of a domain in $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

Take any random example of $z^2 g(z)$ and two points at which its antiderivative has the same value. There is no reason for $\int g$ to vanish along the same path.

Also: the function $1/z$ has nonzero integral over the unit circle, but the integral of $z^2(1/z)= z$ is zero along every closed path.